Pipenvの使い方がわからない
二つのディレクトリ、d1とd2があります。
d1では昔からpipenvを使っていて、pipenvにjuypterをインストールし、そのpython仮想環境でライブラリなどをインストールし、使っていました。
d2は新しく作成した方のディレクトリなんですが、こっちにもpipenvで仮想環境を作り、jupyterをインストールして使用したところ、なぜかd1の環境と繋がっていて、d1でインストールしたライブラリのバージョンとd2でインストールした同じライブラリのバージョンが被ってしまうという事故が起きました。
これでは仮想環境を別に作った意味がありません。
しかし、インターネットで調べたりすると、こういった方法しか書かれていませんでした。
コマンド入力の流れについて
d1は以下のような方法でjupyter-notebookを開きました。例えばAというライブラリをインストールした場合はこんな感じです
cd d1
pipenv shell
pipenv install A==3.0
jupyter-notebook

d2も同様に
cd

を実行してd1を出てから、
mkdir d2
cd d2
pipenv shell
pipenv install A==3.1
jupyter-notebook

このようにして仮想環境でインストールしたライブラリを使ったのですが、notebookでimportしたら、異なるバージョンが被ってるみたいでエラーが発生しました。私は、別々のディレクトリで仮想環境を作ればそれで問題ないと思っていたので、d1とd2で行った作業が繋がってるとは思っていませんでした。
これはどこが間違っているのでしょうか？

どのように使用しているか不明なので, 間違いがあっても指摘できません。(各ディレクトリーで) どのようにパッケージを installし, どのように activateしてますか？ (質問を編集し情報を書き加えてみてください)

この辺の記事にヒントがあるかもしれませんね。Why is pipenv still using the global jupyter (/usr/bin/python3) and not encapsulated on its own environment?, Is there a way to use pipenv with Jupyter notebook?, Python's virtual environments

コメントありがとうございます。質問文を編集しました。あと記事の方も読んでみます。

あるいはこんな記事あたりが該当してそうですね。IPython/Jupyter の設定も pipenv で管理する, Windows11で、WSL＋pipenv+Jupyterの環境構築, pyenvとpipenvで、快適Python生活（Windows向け）, 【Python】Jupyter Notebookのインストールと環境構築, pipenv環境でjupyterを使う際のkernel設定, Pythonの環境管理ツール良し悪し

仮想環境は別のものになっていいますか? pipenv shell した時の結果で表示されている仮想環境は見比べていますか? (d1とd2の共通の親にPipenvがあったら同じ仮想環境に入りますよね。ここに書いてある情報だと違う仮想環境という確信は持てません)
jupyter-notebook は仮想環境の中にインストールしていますか? 「仮想環境の外」の jupyter-notebook を起動していたら仮想環境は無関係ですよね? (仮想環境にjupyterインストールしてないのは省略されただけなのかどうか)
などなど、端折られていることが多すぎて「いくらでも起こりそうで答えられない」という質問になってしまってます。

"なぜかd1の環境と繋がっていて、d1でインストールしたライブラリのバージョンとd2でインストールした同じライブラリのバージョンが被ってしまうという事故が起きました。"  "notebookでimportしたら、異なるバージョンが被ってるみたいでエラーが発生しました。" あたりも「質問者さんの解釈」の表現になっていて、いったい何が起きたのか? が他人にはまったく伝わらないように感じます。

まず私は、d1とd2で別々の仮想環境を構築したつもりでした。なのでd1で仮想環境に入ってインストールしたライブラリと、d2で仮想環境に入ってインストールしたライブラリは違う環境にいるのでバージョンが異なっていても問題ないと思っていました。しかし、importしたときに発生したエラーを見ると、同じ環境に同じライブラリの二つのバージョンをインストールしていると書かれていました。d1とd2の仮想環境が繋がっているというのはこういう意味でいいました。



d1とd2の共通の親にPipenvがあったら同じ仮想環境に入りますよね。


確認したらホームディレクトリにPipfileがありました。これが原因なんでしょうか？
しかし、サブディレクトリ内でPipenvで仮想環境を作ろうとしても、うまくいかなかったので、勝手にホームディレクトリのpipenvを使っていることになっているかもしれないです。


importしたときに発生したエラーを見ると、同じ環境に同じライブラリの二つのバージョンをインストールしていると書かれていました。 日本語で「同じ環境に同じライブラリの二つのバージョンをインストールしている」と書かれていたのですか? そうでないならその表現は「質問者さんの解釈」です。こういうimport文を書いたらこういうエラーが出た、というのが 正確に引用 されてないと結局なにも伝わってません



確認したらホームディレクトリにPipfileがありました。 これのせいで「同じ仮想環境に入っている」はありそうです。実際どうなんですか?




正確に引用 されてないと結局なにも伝わってません


このようなサイトを使うのは初心者なので、今後改善します

解決しました。サブディレクトリを新しく作り、そこにpipenvを新しくインストールしたらうまくいきました

自己解決しました。
これまでに発生した問題とその原因
サブディレクトリ、d1とd2がある　
d1に移動して pipenv shell を実行し、仮想環境に入れば、d2に移動してから入った仮想環境に影響は出ないと思っていたが、どちらも同じ環境だった
cd d2
pipenv shell

cd d1
pipenv shell

このように、ディレクトリさえ分ければ勝手に新しい仮想環境が作られると思っていた
原因は、仮想環境で使用するパッケージを一括管理している[Pipfile]がホームディレクトリにあったため、d1に移動してから入った仮想環境も、d2で入った仮想環境も同じ環境になっていたと考えられる
解決方法
ホームディレクトリにあった[Pipfile,Pipfile.lock]をd1に移動させた
次に、d2で新しくpipenvをインストールした
これにより、d2に新しく[Pipfile]が作成された
cd d2
pip install pipenv

d2に移動したら、改めてpipenvをインストールする必要があり、これにより新しい仮想環境を作ることができた
結論
pipenvの仮想環境の状態を管理する[Pipfile]が置いてあるディレクトリの場所が間違っていたためにこのような問題が発生した

質問について, 正確な情報が不足していて どのような状況なのか今ひとつはっきりしません
推測としてひとつ考えられるのは
d1 での pipenv shell で activateしたまま, exitを行わず
d2 で pipenv shell を行い
その際に発生するエラーを無視して操作を続行した
... というもの
複数のプロジェクトを同一として管理してしまう状況は (上記のエラーで無いとするなら),
無理すれば(意図的に操作すれば)作れるだろうけれど, 質問内容からは読み取れない
また, 別解のように, プロジェクト毎に pipenvをインストールする必要はないでしょう
(以下の動作確認)

pipenvで NumPy のバージョン違いの動作確認
raspi@mypc:~/proj/py$ mkdir dmy1
raspi@mypc:~/proj/py$ cd dmy1/
raspi@mypc:~/proj/py/dmy1$ pipenv install numpy
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /home/raspi/proj/py/dmy1/Pipfile
Using default python from /usr/bin/python3 (3.10.12) to create virtualenv...
⠹ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.10.12.final.0-64 in 1598ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/raspi/.local/share/virtualenvs/dmy1-S4VU6qtT, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/raspi/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==24.0, setuptools==69.5.1, wheel==0.43.0
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: /home/raspi/.local/share/virtualenvs/dmy1-S4VU6qtT
(略)

raspi@mypc:~/proj/py/dmy1$ pipenv run python
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.26.4'
>>>

別プロジェクト (別バージョン)
raspi@mypc:~/proj/py/dmy1$ cd ..
raspi@mypc:~/proj/py$ mkdir dmy2
raspi@mypc:~/proj/py$ cd dmy2
raspi@mypc:~/proj/py/dmy2$ pipenv install numpy==1.24
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /home/raspi/proj/py/dmy2/Pipfile
Using default python from /usr/bin/python3 (3.10.12) to create virtualenv...
⠼ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.10.12.final.0-64 in 222ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/raspi/.local/share/virtualenvs/dmy2-soYli4Ca, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/raspi/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==24.0, setuptools==69.5.1, wheel==0.43.0
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
Virtualenv location: /home/raspi/.local/share/virtualenvs/dmy2-soYli4Ca
(略)

raspi@mypc:~/proj/py/dmy2$ pipenv run python
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.24.0'
>>>
raspi@mypc:~/proj/py/dmy2$ cd ../dmy1/
raspi@mypc:~/proj/py/dmy1$ pipenv run python
Python 3.10.12 (main, Nov 20 2023, 15:14:05) [GCC 11.4.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.__version__
'1.26.4'
>>>


pipenv のメッセージにも現れていますが
実際のパッケージの位置は (指定がなければ通常は) ~/.local/share/virtualenvs/ 以下にあります
(ただし環境によっては異なるかもしれない)
$ ls ~/.local/share/virtualenvs
dmy1-S4VU6qtT  dmy2-soYli4Ca


環境の初期化・リセットなど行う際に, 消してしまうのも一つの手
(特別に位置を指定しない限り) ここに存在しないものは仮想環境がないと言えるでしょう

また, プロジェクトディレクトリーで pipenv --venv でも確認可能
